# Encrypt passwords in config.properties file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, password-encryption

I am running a bunch of shell scripts which uses the properties in config.properties file.. it has database connection details, passwords.. etc., 
I just want to encrypt the passwords.. so that when someone looks at the properties file they shouldn't be able to use it. 
Also I don't want to change the permissions on the file, I want only the passwords to be encrypted

I know there are few ways.. like using java or using any encryption algorithm but I don't want to use java.

I am running the shell scripts on CentOS.. sample scripts looks like below..

### config.properties

```
    DatabaseHostName=test_host
    DatabasePort=4898
    DatabaseUserName=test_user
    # MY DB Password here is visible.. I want to encrypt this
    DatabasePassword=password123
```

### script.sh

```
    #sourcing the above properties file here
    source ./config.properties
    export PGPASSWORD=${DatabasePassword}
    psql -h ${DatabaseHostName} -p ${DatabasePort} ${DatabaseUserName} -c "select * from table_name;"
```

my both files are under the same folder

Comment: This should help point you in a good direction.
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121132/how-to-use-encrypted-password-in-shell-script-aix

Comment: How will you protect the encryption key?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem, whatever encryption you put in the file, you'd need to be able to reverse in the script. So anyone who can see the script can figure out how to decode the passwords.

Comment: Your best bet is to make sure only the user that runs the database is able to see the file, by setting its read permissions to owner-only.

Answer (score 0):

command encrypt:

```
echo 'hoge' | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa > pass.rsa
```

command decrypt:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey /root/.ssh/id_rsa -in pass.rsa
```

config modify:

```
DatabasePassword=S03EXE -> DatabasePassword=$(openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa -in pass.rsa)
```